# I want to remove one particular word (which is the name of someone) from appearing in atuo predict option

Tags: keyboard

There is a particular name of a person who was my EX and i used to exchange a lot of chats with him. Now that I have moved on, still my android suggests his name when i type certain combination of words. How can i solve this issue

Comment: Your Android version, model name, keyboard app name, device status: rooted/non-rooted?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the words used by the keyboard in the prediction, you can remove a particular word by long press on that particular word,a optipn will appear to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If your keyboard doesn't have a option after long pressing the required word to be hidden/forgotten,you can clear the whole history,a bit extreme but it's pretty easy from the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by removing it from Personal Dictionary.

- You can access Personal Dictionary in.

*settings* > *Languge and input* > *Personal Dictionary*

There is also possiblity that name is showing because of saved contacts.

- To disable it go to *Spell Checker* in Language and Input and uncheck *look up for contacts*.